# Specify version with RDEPENDS in package group

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have multiple version for opencv, but bibake installed the version 3.4.3 default.

```
=== Matching recipes: ===
opencv:
  meta-rcar-gen3-adas  3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4
  meta-oe              4.1.0
  meta-rcar-gen3-adas  2.4.11+gitAUTOINC+707d10f115
  meta-rcar-gen3-adas  3.2+gitAUTOINC+70bbf17b13
```

the [yocto offical documents](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/3.1.20/ref-manual/ref-variables.html#term-RDEPENDS) mentioned the variable `RDEPENDS` supports operator for specify versions.

then i specified the version to 4.1.0 for opencv in package group.

```
SUMMARY = "Requirement packages"
PR = "r1"

inherit packagegroup

RDEPENDS:${PN} = " \
        opencv (>= 4.1.0)\
        libopencv-core-dev \
        libopencv-highgui-dev \
        libopencv-imgproc-dev \
        libopencv-objdetect-dev \
        libopencv-ml-dev \
        opencv-apps \
        opencv-dev \
        protobuf \
        gdb \
        libsdl2 \
        libgpiod \
        libgpiod-tools \
"
```

Appeared the failure message, why??

The version list has v4.1.0, but the error message show `nothing provides v4.1.0 for opencv`.

> nothing provides opencv >= 4.1.0 needed by packagegroup-user-requirements-1.0-r1.noarch

```bash
ERROR: core-image-weston-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/dell/workspace/yocto-v5.1.0-h3ulcb-kf/h3ulcb/build/tmp/work/h3ulcb-poky-linux/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /home/dell/workspace/yocto-v5.1.0-h3ulcb-kf/h3ulcb/build/tmp/work/h3ulcb-poky-linux/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/dell/workspace/yocto-v5.1.0-h3ulcb-kf/h3ulcb/build/tmp/work/h3ulcb-poky-linux/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/home/dell/workspace/yocto-v5.1.0-h3ulcb-kf/h3ulcb/build/tmp/work/h3ulcb-poky-linux/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/rootfs --setopt=logdir=/home/dell/workspace/yocto-v5.1.0-h3ulcb-kf/h3ulcb/build/tmp/work/h3ulcb-poky-linux/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/home/dell/workspace/yocto-v5.1.0-h3ulcb-kf/h3ulcb/build/tmp/work/h3ulcb-poky-linux/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo --nogpgcheck install bash coreutils dnf git htop i2c-tools inx-cluster kernel-module-qos matchbox-terminal omx-user-module optee-client packagegroup-base-extended packagegroup-bsp packagegroup-core-boot packagegroup-core-eclipse-debug packagegroup-core-sdk packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target packagegroup-core-tools-debug packagegroup-core-tools-profile packagegroup-graphics-renesas-proprietary packagegroup-graphics-renesas-wayland packagegroup-gstreamer1.0-plugins packagegroup-user-requirements packagegroup-mm packagegroup-multimedia-kernel-modules packagegroup-multimedia-libs packagegroup-radio packagegroup-wayland-community psplash qosif-tp-user-module qosif-user-module rpm run-postinsts u-boot v4l-utils vim vspmif-tp-user-module weston weston-examples weston-init weston-xwayland locale-base-en-us locale-base-en-gb' returned 1:
DNF version: 4.2.2
cachedir: /home/dell/workspace/yocto-v5.1.0-h3ulcb-kf/h3ulcb/build/tmp/work/h3ulcb-poky-linux/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/cache/dnf
Added oe-repo repo from /home/dell/workspace/yocto-v5.1.0-h3ulcb-kf/h3ulcb/build/tmp/work/h3ulcb-poky-linux/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
repo: using cache for: oe-repo
not found other for:
not found modules for:
not found deltainfo for:
not found updateinfo for:
oe-repo: using metadata from Tue 22 Nov 2022 03:02:16 AM UTC.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Tue 22 Nov 2022 03:02:16 AM UTC.
No module defaults found
--> Starting dependency resolution
--> Finished dependency resolution
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides opencv >= 4.1.0 needed by packagegroup-user-requirements-1.0-r1.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/dell/workspace/yocto-v5.1.0-h3ulcb-kf/h3ulcb/build/tmp/work/h3ulcb-poky-linux/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.855803
ERROR: Task (/home/dell/workspace/yocto-v5.1.0-h3ulcb-kf/h3ulcb/build/../poky/meta/recipes-graphics/images/core-image-weston.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 9003 tasks of which 9002 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/dell/workspace/yocto-v5.1.0-h3ulcb-kf/h3ulcb/build/../poky/meta/recipes-graphics/images/core-image-weston.bb:do_rootfs
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Successfully built the image after I try to set the version conditions as `> 2.0`, but the version still is v3.4.3 for opencv.

```
SUMMARY = "Requirement packages"
PR = "r1"

inherit packagegroup

RDEPENDS:${PN} = " \
        opencv (>= 2.0)\
        libopencv-core-dev \
        libopencv-highgui-dev \
        libopencv-imgproc-dev \
        libopencv-objdetect-dev \
        libopencv-ml-dev \
        opencv-apps \
        opencv-dev \
        protobuf \
        gdb \
        libsdl2 \
        libgpiod \
        libgpiod-tools \
"
```

how to specify the package version in package group? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set PREFERRED_VERSION_package = "version" in your local.conf.
In your case:

PREFERRED_VERSION_opencv = "4.1.0"

The reason is that versions are not evaluated by bitbake itself, but by the package manager you selected (like rpm). So you need to tell bitbake which version to build such that the package manager has the version requested.